# R - calculating values assigned to the same number

Tags: r, if-statement, rows

I have a question regarding this data:

```
data =
1   time    3
2    20 0
3    20 0
4    20 0
5   350 1
6   350 1
7   350 1
8   10  0
9   20  1
10  37  0
11  37  0
12  50  1
13  50  1
14  40  0
15  40  0
16  40  0
```

I want to summarize the time that someone spent looking at 1 (as indexed in column 3). Time always assigned the total looking time when 1 was looked at - so I need to summarize only the first time when 1 is newly indicated - something like 350 + 20 + 50.

An `if`-loop like:

```
if (data$3 == 1) {
  sum <- data[:,2] }
```

does not work, as all the values get summarized. I will need something that addresses always only the first 1 after a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ddply` from plyr package (mydata is your data and col3 is actually column 3 in your data with the name col3.

mydata

```
> mydata
   col1 time col3
1     1   20    0
2     2   20    0
3     3   20    0
4     4  350    1
5     5  350    1
6     6  350    1
7     7   10    0
8     8   20    1
9     9   37    0
10   10   37    0
11   11   50    1
12   12   50    1
13   13   40    0
14   14   40    0
15   15   40    0

library(plyr)
ddply(mydata,.(col3), summarize, mysum=sum(unique(time)))

  col3 mysum
1    0   107
2    1   420
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = read.table(text = '
1   time    3
2    20 0
3    20 0
4    20 0
5   350 1
6   350 1
7   350 1
8   10  0
9   20  1
10  37  0
11  37  0
12  50  1
13  50  1
14  40  0
15  40  0
16  40  0
', header = TRUE)

data$first <- sequence(rle(data$time)$lengths)
data

sum(data$time[data$first==1 & data$X3==1])

# [1] 420
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 <- unique(df[df$X3 == 1, c("time", "X3")])
sum(df2$time)
```

Comment: Note that our answers give different results if `X3` = 1 in the first three rows because `20` appears in `time` in two different groups and `X3` would be 1 in both groups.

Comment: @Mark Miller, thanks a lot for pointing out this issue with my answer! Your solution is much better.